# Why suddenly much higher costs in Google Cloud Functions (Cloud Scheduler)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I usually had to pay $0.10 per function, which made about a few cents a month. Now it costs a few dollars and seems to come from non-firebase services, which I dont understand.
[Image of Cost Increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdEAG.png)

I have 2 projects. One of them I didnt even touch and suddenly the costs are higher and is shown under the description "Jobs".

[Image of non firebase services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGdWE.png)

Does anyone know, why that could be the case? I dont know where these costs come from and I also find it weird, that the dont stay the same. Would be incredibly thankful for any help. :)

[Image of sudden percentage increase for Cloud Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmG72.png)

I tried to look for a solution or the origin of the cost increase, but I couldnt find the reason for it. Since I didnt even change anything for the one project and still the costs increased that date I have no explanation for it :(

Comment: Same issue here, I only deploy 2 scheduled functions but i got charged about 9 dollar in three days.

Comment: Same issue here. Had a scheduler jobs set to run only on weekdays, and I had a spike in cloud scheduler costs spanning Friday, the entire weekend, and Monday. During the week (Friday/Monday) the service it was triggering had completely normal logs, and there are no logs (i.e. no service activity) on the weekend - as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and  ended up contacting support. They informed me that it is an internal issue and they are dealing with it.

> Please be informed that the increase in charges for Cloud Scheduler is
> related to an internal incident which is already being tracked by the
> Cloud Scheduler Engineering team.

Apparently a solution has been launched and it should reflect changes when the billing UI picks it up.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know. That gives clarity! :)

Comment: Any update on this? Billing support just keep saying charges is on account level that i already know, They didn't give me a answer

Comment: My pricing has now been resolved.... hope the change is reflecting for you too!

Comment: Same here, Glad everyone problem has solved.